# How to record system sound from macbook

Tags: audio

I'm trying to record system sound from my macbook while simultaneously record the screen.

Is there an option for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make screen recordings using QuickTime (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH5882?locale=en_US) or 3rd party software such as ScreenFlow (https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm)

I prefer ScreenFlow because it's so customizable, is more akin to movie editing software than anything, and the exported video files can be compressed in many different ways. It also supports recording your iPhone/iPad screen.